# How to switch to truffleruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, truffleruby

I'd like to try running Rails 6 with TruffleRuby, so I installed truffleruby-22.0.0.2 with rbenv, added in my Gemfile `ruby 'truffleruby-22.0.0.2` and ran `bundle install`, but that didn't work. I got an error with "... error parsing Gemfile: Illformed requirement..."

What's the right way to use Rails with TruffleRuby?

Comment: According to the docs, https://github.com/oracle/truffleruby#truffleruby-runtime-configurations, you are supposed to install with your Ruby Manager/Installer

Comment: Can you share your Gemfile or part of it (especially the beginning and exactly what you added)?

Answer (score 1):

If this is still relevant: you can see here https://github.com/oracle/truffleruby/blob/master/doc/user/compatibility.md that as of now Truffle Ruby aims to be compatible with MRI Ruby 3.0.3, so it sets the `RUBY_VERSION` env variable to 3.0.3 and this is the value you should set in your Gemfile.

Unfortunately, when you do so `rbenv` can't detect that you want to use Truffle Ruby instead of MRI. So you should also run `export RBENV_VERSION=truffleruby+graalvm-dev` and then `bundler` would target to 3.0.3 while `rbenv` would use Truffle Ruby.

To know what is the target version detected by `bundler` you can specify any valid ruby version (like 3.1.2 or something) and running `bundle` would output more clarifying error message like this:

```
Your Ruby version is 3.0.3, but your Gemfile specified 3.1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

A long shot, but using another Ruby implementation with Rails raising this error is related to the way you declare your Ruby version in your Gemfile.

**Traditional way:**

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.1.4'
# ...
```

**Other Ruby implementation way example:**

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.1.4', :engine => 'jruby', :engine_version => '9.4.3.0'
# ...
```